# What are Hive Common Use Cases?

Tags: hadoop, hive, nosql

I'm new to Hive; so, I'm not sure how companies use Hive.  Let me give you a scenario and see if I'm conceptually correct about the use of Hive.

Let's say my company wants to keep some web server log files and be able to always search through and analyze the logs.  So, I create a table columns of which correspond to the columns in the log file.  Then I load the log file into the table.  Now, I can start query the data.  So, as the data comes in at future dates, I just keep adding the data to this table, and thus I always have my log files as a table in Hive that I can search through and analyze.

Is that scenario above a common use? And if it is, then how do I keep adding new log files to the table? Do I have to keep adding them to the table manually each day?

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use Hive, for analysis over static datasets, but if you have streaming logs, I really wouldn't suggest Hive for this. It's not a search engine and will take minutes just to find any reasonable data you're looking for.

HBase would probably be a better alternative if you must stay within the Hadoop ecosystem. (Hive can query Hbase)

Use Splunk, or the open source alternatives of Solr / Elasticsearch / Graylog if you want reasonable tools for log analysis.

But to answer your questions

> how do I keep adding new log files to the table? Do I have to keep adding them to the table manually each day?

Use an `EXTERNAL` Hive table over an HDFS location for your logs. Use Flume to send log data to that path (or send your logs to Kafka, and from Kafka to HDFS, as well as a search/analytics system)

You only need to update the table if you're adding date partitions (which you should because that's how you get faster Hive queries). You'd use `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` to detect missing partitions on HDFS. Or run `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION` yourself on a schedule. Note: Confluent's HDFS Kafka Connect will automatically create Hive table partitions for you

If you must use Hive, you can improve the queries better if you convert the data into ORC or Parquet format

Comment: You said that I can use flume to bring in data to HDFS.  But how is this data added to the same table?  The answer is probably very simple to you and you assume that I know. But how is that data added to the table?

Comment: All Hive is is metadata over an HDFS location. Put more data at the HDFS path, Hive can query it

Comment: I don't think you understand my question.  I understand that I can use Hive to query any data on HDFS; but I want them all to be part of the same table.  To clarify, let's assume I was MySQL; then as the data comes in, I simply insert it into the same table, and then I can make query over the same table.  That's what I want that let's say for the next 10 years as the data comes in, my process would add the data to the same table, and thus in the query, I query the same table.

Comment: Well, if your data was in mysql, you'd use Sqoop to get it to Hive, or if you have Kafka, then Kafka Connect... No I don't understand your question because you just changed the input data. My primary point remains the same. Put the data in the same HDFS location that Hive looks at, then Hive still works without manual intervention **unless** you add table partitions